# How to check page level authentication in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an application in which there are multiple roles and privileges for user.
Based on whether the currently logged in user I should check whether the user has rights to access the particular page. The hasAccess value will be stored in a boolean and can be accessed like

```
rootScope.globals.adminYes
```

If adminYes is true then only the admin page will be shown to the user.
I need to check whether the value of `adminYes` is `true` and then render the page or else if `adminYes` is `false` then the user should not be able to view the page and a popup message should appear saying the user has insufficient privileges.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have defined pages url/state in database? or you will define it as soon as you come to know like , oh its admin, he can go for this this this page and its guest, he can go for this?

Comment: Put `adminYes` flag in a `service` .. and when ever you need to show get the value from the service and decide whether you can show it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to check whether the user can view the page or not. Suppose say I have admin and a user. Admin can view the page where as user cannot view the page.

Save the value in a service and then depending on the user decide whether the page can be displayed or not.

For simpilicity I am modifying the `hasAccess` value in the controller. In real time we need to get the value from the DB and show the pages accordingly.

**script.js**

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, Service) {
  // get from DB whether the user is admin or not.
  // USer role details also we should get from the DB.
  $scope.admin = function() {
    Service.setAccess(true);
  };

  $scope.user = function() {
    Service.setAccess(false);
    alert('No Access');
  };

  $scope.hasAccess = function() {
    return Service.getAccess();
  };

});

myApp.service('Service', function() {

  var hasAccess = true;

  this.getAccess = function() {
      return hasAccess;
  };

  this.setAccess = function(access) {
    hasAccess = access;
  };

});
```

**html:**

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="admin()">Admin</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="user()">User</button>

    <div>
      <div ng-show="hasAccess()">
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 2px solid black; background-color: green;">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fPsOM8Q1jFCgGiD9Nruk?p=preview).